# Making Azure Web Application respond on IP address

Tags: azure, networking

I came across site that does SEO checking and after running it against my Azure Web Application it came back with failed "IP Canonicalization Test", where it expected to see redirect from IP to actual site.
My question is: how can I configure Azure to respond with my Web Application when accessed by IP address?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Based on comments/replies it seems my question is not clear enough, apologies for this. Here is further clarification: According to "IP Cononicalization Test" your site should respond only on name i.e. www.example.com, but also on IP address, so if public IP address for www.example.com is 12.34.56.78, customer should be able to enter 12.34.56.78 in their browser and get redirected to example.com. Hopefully it clarifies the question

Comment: Can we have more detail on the expected behavior? It's not clear to me. At all.

Comment: Actually, a domain mane, e.g. `www.example.com`, gets translated to an IP address, e.g. 12.34.56.78, not the other way around. IP only understands IP addresses (an IP address is a 32-bit integer, usually represented in the dotted-decimal notation). IP does not know anything about a domain name.